# window.location.state does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, json, windows, internet-explorer-11

I have one situation,where i need to pass some json from one window to new window in the same domain.I have first window lets say it window1 and second window,let say it window2.

I have following code in window1:

```
var params = [
    'height=750',
    'width=720',
    'scrollbars=yes',
    'left=0',
    'top=0',
    'fullscreen=no', // only works in IE, but here for completeness
    'location=no'
].join(',');

var port = location.port;
var url = "http://" + hostName + ':' + port + "/isecalreport" +       location.search;
var newWindow = window.open(url,'photocal_report',params);

while(true){
    if(newWindow! == undefined) {
        newWindow.location.state={payloadFromIseCalWeekly : payloadFromIseCalWeekly,instrumentIdObj : instrumentIdObj};
        break;
    }
}
```

Code in window2:

```
var payloadFromIseCalWeekly = location.state.payloadFromIseCalWeekly ? location.state.payloadFromIseCalWeekly : {};
```

I want to make use of the json set in window.location.state.

So the problem is ,It works fine in chrome ,mozilla,but fails in IE 11(when debugger is not open.)
When i open debugger in IE11 ,it works fine.

I debugged it and found out that after the instruction which is opening the new window ,the next instruction get run and it doesnot find the new window object.
Its strange as it works when developer console is open.

It would be good if i can get insights about how to resolve the issue.

My aim is to open a new window ,to which i need to pass some data and using that data i want to do an API call.

Comment: Please use the formatting tools to properly format your code.

Comment: Thanks @Soviut  I will keep in mind when answering or questioning

Answer (score 0):

With few exceptions, you cannot tell one window, tab or frame to talk to another directly. This is to prevent malicious scripts in one of these contexts from hijacking another across pages.

To cope with this, you have two options, you can use [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) or simply pass your data via the URL that you open in the new window. There are technically more options if you're on the same domain, but I recommend against going down that rabbit hole.

Sending data via the URL is a one-way affair. You can send query string variables in the URL that the new window can read, but it can't send anything back to the window that created it.

[`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), on the other hand, can be used to communicate between multiple contexts and across domains. It is considered secure because it requires that all participants be listening for messages, rather than allowing direct code access.

Your various pages can listen for messages with a simple event listener.

```
// listen for incoming messages on this page
window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    // this is the handler function

    // do we trust where this was sent from?
    if (event.origin !== "http://example.com") {
        // if so, print the resulting event object
        console.log('message received', e);
    }
}, false);
```

You can then send a message from another page to your window.

```
// the * is the targetOrigin, read the docs!
newWindow.postMessage("some message data", "*");
```

Comment: Thanks @soviut ,I chose search params method.One question comes in my mind .Right now I am working on a single page application,in which only one html file is there ,where mounting and unmounting keeps on happening.Now when i open a new window it opens that same html file with different component mounted.Do you think post message will work there ?

Comment: yes, your SAP can listen for multiple types of messages. Also, try to avoid opening new windows at all if you can help it, since window.open is blocked by most popup blockers.